# How to use substring function in oracle in date columns which is in number format

Tags: oracle

I have a Column Called `FILLD_DT` in a table which has `number(8)` data type format. I am trying to use this column and create a new column called Derived date in my own table.
Ex: Filled Date = `20170107`

Below is the query I am using and I am getting

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER

```
(CASE WHEN PERD = 'Beginning' AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,5,2) IN (01,02,03) AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,1,4) = 2017  THEN  '20170101'
      WHEN PERD = 'Beginning' AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,5,2) IN (04,05,06) AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,1,4) = 2017  THEN '20170501'
      WHEN PERD = 'Beginning' AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,5,2) IN (07,08,09) AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,1,4) = 2017  THEN '20170701'
      WHEN PERD = 'Beginning' AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,5,2) IN (10,11,12) AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,1,4) = 2017  THEN  '20171001'
 ELSE FILLD_DT
 END ) AS DRVD_DATE
```

please help me understand

below is the full query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
SRC_ID,
SEQ_NBR,
PROD_ID,
TYPE_CD,
FILLD_DT,
PRCSD_DT,
(CASE WHEN PERD = 'Beginning' AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,5,2) IN (01,02,03) AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,1,4) = 2017  THEN  '20170101'
 WHEN PERD = 'Beginning' AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,5,2) IN (04,05,06) AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,1,4) = 2017  THEN '20170401'
WHEN PERD = 'Beginning' AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,5,2) IN (07,08,09) AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,1,4) = 2017  THEN '20170701'
WHEN PERD = 'Beginning' AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,5,2) IN (10,11,12) AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,1,4) = 2017  THEN  '20171001'
WHEN PERD = 'middle' AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,5,2) IN (01,02,03) AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,1,4) = 2017  THEN  '20170115'
 WHEN PERD = 'middle' AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,5,2) IN (04,05,06) AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,1,4) = 2017  THEN '20170415'
WHEN PERD = 'middle' AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,5,2) IN (07,08,09) AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,1,4) = 2017  THEN '20170715'
WHEN PERD = 'middle' AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,5,2) IN (10,11,12) AND SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,1,4) = 2017  THEN  '20171015'
ELSE FILLD_DT
END)
FROM
SOURCE
```

and I modified the query to your suggestion and I am getting the below error

> [Error] Execution (8: 29): ORA-01830: date format picture ends
>   before converting entire input string

```
SELECT DISTINCT
SRC_ID,
SEQ_NBR,
PROD_ID,
TYPE_CD,
FILLD_DT,
PRCSD_DT,
( trunc( to_date( FILLD_DT || '01', 'yyyymmdd' ), 'Q' )
 ) AS DRVD_DATE
FROM
SOURCE
WHERE
SRC_ID = 163662
```

Comment: I hope I followed the correct formating.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number, which represents a DATE, to character before converting it to DATE.

DECLARE
    FILLD_DT        NUMBER(0008) := 20170107;
    DRVD_DATE       DATE;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000);
    DRVD_DATE :=
        TO_DATE
            (
            TO_CHAR(FILLD_DT)
            ,'YYYYMMDD'
            );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Derived Date: ' || TO_CHAR(DRVD_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd'));
END;
Not understanding what you are trying to do with "FILLD_DT || '01'".  At best that would give you a string of '2017010701' which doesn't match your DATE format string of 'YYYYMMDD'.

Comment: Can't seem to get the code snippet to format correctly.

Comment: My result has to assign the Beginning of the Quarter  and middle of the quarter for that particular beginning quarter. For example if my filled date is 20170326 and PRD is 'beginning' then I have to assign 20170101 similarly if my filled date is 20170326 and PRD is 'middle' then I have to assign 20170105 since the date and month fall in the first quarter.  And as well the date in YYYYMMDD but the data type is Number(8).

Comment: I see.  The original question was how to convert a number, which represents a date, to a value in a variable having DATE data type.  I believe that has been answered.

Comment: But after converting the number to a DATE you can't use "SUBSTR(FILLD_DT,5,2) IN (07,08,09)" because the DATE isn't a STRING.  Instead you would want to do something like "FILLD_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Jul-2017','dd-Mon-yyyy') AND TO_DATE('30-Sep-2017 23:5959','dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')" to define Q1.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you're using oracle 10g or gratter and the format in FILLD_DT is "YYYYMMDD".

This work in Oracle 11g:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(FILLD_DT,'YYYYMMDD') AS Derived_date  FROM SOURCE;
```

Just in case if a single value in FILLD_DT not match with the given format it will return an error. To prevent the miss parse you can skip those records using a user defined function and a case statement.

Some data to play with:

```
CREATE TABLE SOME_DATA (
  NUMBER_DATE NUMBER(8)
);

INSERT INTO SOME_DATA VALUES(20170912);
INSERT INTO SOME_DATA VALUES(20030530);
INSERT INTO SOME_DATA VALUES(19901131);
INSERT INTO SOME_DATA VALUES(20170731);
INSERT INTO SOME_DATA VALUES(20170230);
COMMIT;
```

Function to validate if is a valid date:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IS_DATE(V_DATE IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
    V_DATE1 DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT TO_DATE(V_DATE,'YYYYMMDD') INTO V_DATE1 FROM DUAL;
        RETURN 1;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN 0;
END;
```

Finally the query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE IS_DATE(NUMBER_DATE) 
        WHEN 1 THEN TO_DATE(NUMBER_DATE,'YYYYMMDD') 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS Derived_date,NUMBER_DATE
FROM SOME_DATA ;
```

[User defined function](https://community.oracle.com/thread/935741?start=0&tstart=0)